# how to convert QDeclarativeItem to QImage

Tags: qt

I need to convert QDeclarativeItem  Object into QImage object in nokia Qt , is there is any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the bounding rectangle of your item with

```
QRectF QGraphicsItem::boundingRect()
```

You will also need a pointer to your QDeclarativeView, which you can use to render this rectangle into a QImage with

```
void QGraphicsView::render ( QPainter * painter,
    const QRectF & target = QRectF(), const QRect & source = QRect(),
    Qt::AspectRatioMode aspectRatioMode = Qt::KeepAspectRatio )
```

(Untested.)